# Is it possible to create a stored procedure with two insert statements where id/primary_key from the first insert statement will be used in second?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I see that there is a very similiar question already answered that discusses this same issue, but i just cannot seem to understand it. Below is a copy of my code that is in a stored procedure.  I need to somehow, have the second insert statement insert the CompanyID generated from the first, into this second Statement.  I appreciate any help i can get.

Thank You!!

```
@comp_name nvarchar (50),
@City nvarchar (50),
@State nvarchar (10),
@Address ntext,
@Zip_Code nvarchar (50),
@Country nvarchar (50),
@cust_name nvarchar (50),
@CompanyID int
AS
INSERT INTO Company_Listing
(comp_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country)
VALUES (@comp_name, @City, @State, @Address, @Zip_Code, @Country)

INSERT INTO Customer_Listing
(cust_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country, CompanyID)
VALUES (@comp_name,@City,@State,@Address,@Zip_Code,@Country,@CompanyID)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is for SQL Server - Yes, use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):

```
@comp_name nvarchar (50),
@City nvarchar (50),
@State nvarchar (10),
@Address ntext,
@Zip_Code nvarchar (50),
@Country nvarchar (50),
@cust_name nvarchar (50),
@CompanyID int
AS
INSERT INTO Company_Listing
(comp_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country)
VALUES (@comp_name, @City, @State, @Address, @Zip_Code, @Country)

INSERT INTO Customer_Listing
(cust_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country, CompanyId)
VALUES (@comp_name,@City,@State,@Address,@Zip_Code,@Country,SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

From MSDN's documentation on `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: Thank you!  I have never got help with an issue so fast!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Assuming you are using SQL Server ... just use the [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function to retrieve the last inserted identity value.  In other words, replace @CompanyID with SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @MyFirstID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

--now you have your ID from your first insert statement, namely @MyFirstID

Code becomes:

```
@comp_name nvarchar (50),
@City nvarchar (50),
@State nvarchar (10),
@Address ntext,
@Zip_Code nvarchar (50),
@Country nvarchar (50),
@cust_name nvarchar (50),
@CompanyID int
AS
INSERT INTO Company_Listing
(comp_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country)
VALUES (@comp_name, @City, @State, @Address, @Zip_Code, @Country)

INSERT INTO Customer_Listing
(cust_name, City, State, Address, Zip_Code, Country, CompanyID)
VALUES (@comp_name,@City,@State,@Address,@Zip_Code,@Country,SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick up the id of the created record after the first id. This is done differently in different database systems.

For Microsoft SQL Server:

```
set @CompanyId = scope_identity()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you just need to add an interim statement that collects the ID, store it in a variable and then use that in your second statement. So you would need to add something like

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.CompanyTable')
```

Comment: never use ident_current for this, it is not limited to the scope and will return the worng value under race conditions.